# AWS EC2 Windows Server 2019 billing free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm just wondering about the free tier. I've created an EC2 instance with windows server 2019. When I selected it it said "free tier eligible". Does this mean it'll be free forever, will I be charged for something and how can I prevent any extra charges?

Comment: Along the free 750h for the first 12 months, there may be associated resources which may not be completely free (storage, traffic,..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you get 750 Hours per month for a single free tier instance during your first 12 months. Meaning you should just be able to keep it running for the first year of your membership.

More details can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all).